# what causes uwp app to show blank screen on some devices?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

what causes uwp app to show blank screen on some devices,can it be the extended splash screen or is it the os build version,i can figure out what it is?

Am using C# and xaml for development

Comment: When appears the blank screen? At startup?

Comment: Could you specify your problem? A screenshot or [mcve] would be helpful. Besides, have you tried testing with a new Blank projet? Does it have the same issue?